# Grothendieck Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, residue-calculus

In the article: Residues Of Codimension one Singular Holomorphic Distribution,  the author : Takeshi Izawa, states that:

Theorem: Let $X$ an $n$-dimensional compact complex manifold and $\mathcal{G}$ a rank-one locally-free subsheaf of $\Omega_{X}$. We assume that the singular supports of $\Omega_{X}/ \mathcal{G}$ are all isolated. Then we have:

$$ \int_{X}c_{n}(\Omega_{X} \otimes \mathcal{G}^{\vee}) = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^{k}\text{Res}_{p_{j}}  \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
df_{1}^{(j)} \wedge & \cdots & \wedge \,\, df_{n}^{(j)}\\
f_{1}^{(j)} \wedge & \cdots & \wedge f_{n}^{(j)}
\end{array}
\right] $$

where above there is the Grothendieck residue. In this article, the author provides no example of how to calculate this residue.

The Distribution $\mathscr{F}$of codimension one on $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ induced by: $$\omega = (z_{0}^{2} + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2})dz_{3} - (z_{3}z_{0} +  z_{2}z_{1})dz_{0} + (z_{2}z_{0} - z_{3}z_{1})dz_{1} - z_{3}z_{2}dz_{2}$$

It has as singular scheme : $\lbrace 2[i : -1 : 0 : 0], 2[i : 1 : 0 : 0], [0 : 0 : 0 : 1] \rbrace$.

Frankly, I don't know how to calculate the Grothendieck residue for singular points for the above distribution.  References on this subject and examples will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @reuns. In the example, in the question, we would have: $\int_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}c_{3}(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(3))$. I would like to learn effectively how to calculate this grothendieck residue on isolated singularities. Thank you.

Comment: What is $c_{3}(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(3))$

Comment: It is a third class of Chern. Where $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}$ It is the sheaf of the $1$ -differential forms in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the very definition of Grothendieck Residue: Let $\omega = \sum_{j=1}^n f_jdz_j$ be a a local one form defining the distribution around a point $p$ (which we choose to be the origin in the coordinates $z$). Then, for a small polydisc $P$ with essential boundary $\Gamma$ we have
$$
\text{Res}_{p}  \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
df_{1}^{(j)} \wedge & \cdots & \wedge \,\, df_{n}^{(j)}\\
f_{1}^{(j)} \wedge & \cdots & \wedge f_{n}^{(j)}
\end{array}
\right] = \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^n} \int_\Gamma \frac{\det(Jf)}{f_1\dots f_n}dz_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dz_n
$$
where $Jf$ is the jacobian matrix of $(f_1 , \dots, f_n)$. For a reference see [Soares - Lectures on Point Residues](http://www.mat.ufpb.br/mangai/arquivos/residue2002.pdf).

Now for the example. I will go for the last point $(0:0:0:1)$. Then $z_3=1$ and in coordinates $(z_0,z_1,z_2)$ we have
$$
\omega = -(z_{0} +  z_{2}z_{1})dz_{0} + (z_{2}z_{0} - z_{1})dz_{1} - z_{2}dz_{2}
$$
i.e. $f_0 = -z_{0} -z_{2}z_{1}$, $f_1 = z_{2}z_{0} - z_{1}$ and $f_2 = - z_{2}$.
$$
J(f_0,f_1,f_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -z_2 & -z_1 \\
z_2 & -1 & z_0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
whose determinant is $\det J(f_0,f_1,f_2) = -(1+z_2^2)$.  Give the an appropriate polydisc we have that the residue is 
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^3} \int_\Gamma \frac{-(1+z_2^2)dz_0 \wedge dz_1 \wedge dz_2}{(z_0+z_1z_2)(z_0z_2-z_1)z_2} = \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^3} \int_\Gamma\left[\frac{dz_0 \wedge dz_1 \wedge dz_2}{z_0z_1z_2}+ \dots\right] =1
$$
You'll certainly find the technical steps I have not gone through in Soares' notes.

**ADDED:** The other singularities $(i:\pm 1:0:0)$ lie on the open subset $\{z_0 \neq 0 \}$ where the form is 
$$
\omega = (1 + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2})dz_{3}  + (z_{2} - z_{3}z_{1})dz_{1} - z_{3}z_{2}dz_{2}
$$
then $f_1 = (z_{2} - z_{3}z_{1})$, $f_2 = - z_{3}z_{2}$ and $f_3 = (1 + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2})$.
$$
J(f_1,f_2,f_3) = \begin{pmatrix}
-z_3 & 1 & -z_1 \\
0 & -z_3 & -z_2 \\
2z_1 & 2z_2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
whose determinant is $\det J(f_0,f_1,f_2) = -2(z_1^2z_3 +z_2^2z_3+z_2z_1)$. Then
the residue is 
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^3} \int_\Gamma \frac{2(z_1^2z_3 +z_2^2z_3+z_2z_1)dz_1 \wedge dz_2 \wedge dz_3}{(z_{2} - z_{3}z_{1})(1 + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2})z_{3}z_{2}}
$$
where $\Gamma$ is around one of the singularities, that in our chart are $(\pm i ,0,0)$.  Lets compute the residue for $(i,0,0)$.

Then we make a translation $z_1 \mapsto z_1+i$ and compute the residue ate the origin (just to make computations easier). Our integrand becomes
$$
\frac{2((z_1+i)^2z_3 +z_2^2z_3+z_2(z_1+i))}{(z_{2} - z_{3}(z_{1}+i))(1 + (z_{1}+i)^{2} + z_{2}^{2})z_{3}z_{2}} = \frac{2(-z_3+iz_2+2iz_1z_3+z_1^2z_3+z_2^2z_3+z_1z_2)}{(z_2-iz_3-z_1z_3)(2iz_1+z_1^2+z_2^2)z_2z_3} = \\ = \frac{2}{(z_2-iz_3-z_1z_3)z_2} + \frac{-2}{(z_2-iz_3-z_1z_3)(2iz_1+z_1^2+z_2^2)z_2}+ \\+ \frac{2i}{(z_2-iz_3-z_1z_3)(2iz_1+z_1^2+z_2^2)z_3}+ \frac{2z_1}{(z_2-iz_3-z_1z_3)(2iz_1+z_1^2+z_2^2)z_3}
$$
The contributions of each of the four summands to the residue are, respectively $0,1,1,0$. Hence the residue is $2$.

**Alternative approach:** This residue is just the Milnor number of the map $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ at $(i,0,0)$ defined by the dimension of the algebra $$\frac{\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,z_3]_{(i,0,0)}}{(f_1,f_2,f_3)} \simeq \mathbb{C}^2 $$
generated by the classes of $1$ and $z_2$.

Also note that if we change $i$ to $-i$ every thing goes the same way.

Comment: Wonderful. Very good indeed. You solved my problem. Thank you!! Thank you very much !!

Comment: Why does the method used in pontp $[0 : 0 : 0 : 1] $ not work for the double dot $[ i : 1 : 0 : 0]$? The sum of the residues, by a Joanoulou Theorem, in this case has to be equal to $5$, because the distribution has degree one.

Comment: For $z_{1} = 1$, $\text{det}J(f_{0}, f_{2}, f_{3}) = 0$. For Joanoulou's Theorem to be verified, the residual at this double point must be equal to two and I am finding zero. Thanks in advance, any help.

Comment: I'll add these calculations to the answer

Comment: @ Alan Muniz. Thank you,  Thank you very much.

Comment: @AllanRamos compare with your calculations

Comment: Very Good. Thank you so much for your response and for your willingness to help people in this forum. Success for you !! Thank you one more time.

Comment: I realized where I was wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: I promise not to interrupt you anymore with this subject. My accounts are not closing ... Why are the first and second residues  0 and 1 respectively? Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem... The first one you can prove using the property 4 in soares notes page 60. The others are a bit tricky.  One can analyse the integration process and see that we are computing the residue with respect to $(f_1,f_2,z_2)$  and $(f_1,f_2,z_3)$ in the last two terms. These have non degenerate jacobians and the result follows.

Comment: The heuristics is that $f_3=0$ has two components and we ar integrating on a cycle that goes around them. Then the form is holomorphic on one of them, we only have contribution of the other.

Comment: A non-degenerate singularity is one in which the Jacobian is not null, correct? Thanks for your explanation. I will try to understand them and ask you if necessary again..Hahaha

Comment: Correct. If I have the time, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: We can chat anytime about this. (chat) Thank you.